# trouble getting variable to display using .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

HTML:

```
<input type="number" id="input" placeholder="Number.." onkeydown="javascript: 
return event.keyCode === 69 ? false : true"/>
<div class="boxes">
   <div class="decimalBox">
     <p>Decimal:
        <span id="decimalOutput"></span>
     </p>
  </div>
  <div class="binaryBox">
    <p>Binary:
      <span id="binaryOutput"></span>
    </p>
  </div>
```

Javascript:

```
//global variables
var number = document.getElementById('input');  
var decimalOutput = document.getElementById('decimalOutput');
var binaryOutput = document.getElementById('binaryOutput');

number.addEventListener("input", toBinary);

//Converting Decical to Binary by using independent division and taking the 
modulus the number
function toBinary(x){
  var result = [], i;
  for(var i=number;i>0;i=parseInt(i/2)){
     result.push(i%2);
  }
  var binary = result.reverse().join('');
 //returns the result of the array and then reverses the order to create the 
 correct binary order.
  decimalOutput.innerHTML = number.value;
  binaryOutput.innerHTML = binary;
  return binary;
}
```

My question is this. Everything is working except for me being able to display the **binary** variable declared in the **toBinary()** Function. It seems to throw errors and not allow me to actually use that value to display the current input in binary form, however I tested this using parameters and the code runs just fine. I just need help figuring out why this specific case won't work.

Correct way to fix this was @titus suggestion: instead of having "var i = number" in the for loop change it to the value or number. Thanks!

Comment: In your `for` loop you have this: `var i=number`. The number variable is a HTML element not a number, you should use `var i = number.value`.

Comment: BTW, you declare *i* twice, which doesn't cause any issues but might be confusing, *var* is not blocked scoped.

Comment: @titus good call, that got the job done!